# How to sound-amplify my ESP8266

Tags: amplifier, esp8266, sound

I've set up a ESP8266 to play MP3 radio from a web server, using the [ESP8266 Audio](https://github.com/earlephilhower) library. My circuitry is pretty much like this: 
 [image]

My question is, how can I amplify the volume of the sound, as it is not high enough for me. Is it merely  connecting higher voltage to the circuitry, like a 9V battery? If so, how can I know the limits my speaker and my transistor can handle? Is there a max voltage specified for speakers and transistors? Are there ready-made amplifiers for such things?

I would appreciate if someone could tell me **exactly** what kind of products I need in order to amplify the ESP8266. I prefer plugging to the electricity rather than using a battery.

Thanks !

Comment: The output of an audio amplifier is AC. Your darlington transistor produces variable DC that will fry your speaker. The transistors in an audio amplifier are biased. Your transistor is not biased so it will produce extreme distortion and will not be loud. An audio amplifier IC like an LM386 in a circuit shown in its datasheet produces only 0.22W (which is a low level) into an 8 ohm speaker with your 6V supply. An LM1875 amplifier with a 50V supply produces 22W (which is a loud level) into an 8 ohm speaker.

Comment: Your speaker appears to be tiny and has no enclosure so it will sound vert tinny and produce only high frequency sounds.

Comment: @Audioguru:  The ESP8266 doesn't have an analog output.  The library is providing on/off pulses to drive the output.  A single transistor is all it takes.  I'm not saying it'll sound good, but it doesn't require a regular amplifier.

Comment: @Audioguru - So you're saying that all I need is just higher voltage?

Comment: PN2222 NPN Transistor

Comment: Are you really using a 2N2222?  That's a very different thing than the TIP-122 marked in your drawing, and very different from the P-channel MOSFET shown in the drawing.

Comment: Are you really going to ask again if I'm really doing something? Yes it's a different type of transistor. As stated in the question, I'm pretty clueless about electronics, all I know about transistors is that the base controls the flow between the collector and emitter, and what I plugged in my circuit is working besides it's just low volume.

Comment: Sorry.  I asked once then deleted it because I saw the TIP-122 marked in the drawing.  You answered the deleted comment with the name of a different transistor.  Now we've got three potential transistor types:  The P-channel MOSFET as the part is marked, a TIP-122 as marked in the text by the part in the drawing, and now a 2N2222.  Each is different.  It matters which you used.

Comment: You say the ESP8266 produces pulses then are the pulses "Pulse Width Modulation"?

Comment: Many amplifiers today use Pulse Width Modulation which is called "class-D". Instead your transistor produces varying DC to burn out the speaker instead of producing AC like every audio amplifier. Audio amplifiers use at least 2 transistors for "push-pull". The supply voltage of an audio amplifier determines its maximum output level but you do not have an audio amplifier. If the pulses are correct, if the speaker is a larger good one in a proper enclosure and if you have an audio amplifier circuit then the sounds will be excellent.

Comment: @Audioguru - as I stated in the question - I have very little knowledge in electricity, so your above comments aren't really helpful for me. My question is - what do I need in order to amplify the sound coming out of the ESP8266? If you could explain this to someone who has no background in electricity - great. If not - that's fine also.

Comment: We are geeks and talk about electronic details on this website. You need an audio amplifier, the extremely simple circuit you posted is not an audio amplifier.